# How to Host my Angular 4 web App in GCP

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-platform

I want to host my website through google Cloud Platform, But my code is in typescript(Angular 4). Anyone know how to host angular 4 website in GCP please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

- install [friebase-tools](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools)

  > npm install -g firebase-tools
- go project dir,init setting and select Hosting

  > firebase init
- publish you angular web to firebase host

  > firebase deploy
- do complete !!:)

Read more at:
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/

Comment: the OP doesnt mention firebase

Answer (score -1):

It would be useful if you provide more details about the website. If it is static, you can use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website).

If it is not, you can use [App Engine flexible Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/) or [App Engine flexible Custom Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/). Use the Custom Runtime "to use an alternative implementation of Java, Python, Node.js, Go or write in another language".

In any case, I suggest you to start doing the "quickstart" to get familiarized with the solution.